# Android webview ERR_EMPTY_RESPONCE

Tags: android, webview

Hello have this problem on android webview app, trying to load responsive website in app. and getting this error in app:

Webpage is not available The webpage at https://mydomainname.com/
cud not be louded becouse.

NET::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONCE

Website works perfectly, funniest that on iphone works perfectly, and after restarting app I don't get this error, just one time after installation.

EDIT:
I`m thinking of one solution, may some one help my. I`m thinking of making auto refresh one time after app is lounched, do some one have code?

Comment: your link is not open in browser 1st check that than try

Comment: Can you specify your answer? I don't really understand.

Comment: webView is only open the webpage which are exist in real (means are you able to open your url in webbrowser  )

Comment: I wrote: Website works perfectly, funniest that on iphone works perfectly, and after restarting app I don't get this error, just one time after installation